# How to call my saved python file in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in python. I have made a following code:

```
def Synthesis():
    x = input('Enter first Chemical: ')
    y = input('Enter Second Chemical: ')
    if x=='Benzene' and y=='Chloroform':
        print('Available')
    if x=='Methanol' and y=='Methane':
        print('Not Available')
               
        return(x,y)
   

Synthesis()
```

I want the above code in tkinter where I can put the button 'result' and fetch the my 'print' statement in it, ofcourse along with entry1 and entry2 for chemical 1 and chemical 2.

Comment: This is not a "WRITE YOUR CODE" site, youve to include what youve tried so far, and we will correct where the error. I would recommend to do some research of your own first and ask doubts through code here

Comment: Well, I have already made the code and I am not asking to "ANYONE TO WRITE MY CODE", I have a little confusion regarding tkinter. And I was just hoping if someone can just show me right pathway in this platform. Thank you

Comment: how will we know what youve tried with tkinter, if you dont include the what youve tried so far, anyway just keep this in mind while asking next Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*
win=Tk()
res=StringVar()
Label(win,text="Chemical 1").pack()
chem1=Entry(win)
chem2=Entry(win)
result=Entry(win,textvariable=res)
chem1.pack()
Label(win,text="Chemical 2").pack()
chem2.pack()
Label(win,text="Result").pack()
result.pack()
def Synthesis():
    x = chem1.get()
    y = chem2.get()
    if x=='Benzene' and y=='Chloroform':
        res.set('Available')
    elif x=='Methanol' and y=='Methane':
        res.set('Not Available')
Button(win,text="Result",command=Synthesis).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond. But when i run the code it is giving me the result on Python shell. i want the result in my tkinter window itself in ''Result'' Entry box.

Comment: @CharitraGour replace the `print('Available')` with `main = Label(win,text=Available")` and `main.pack()` and later say `main.config(text='Not available')` instead of `print('Not Available')`